# Blocks on left of moodle

Tags: boost, moodle

I have developed a Moodle plugin, which I want im the left side of the page, i.e on the nav-drawer. How do i add my custom block on the left side of Moodle(boost theme) where the navigation drawer currently exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [the Boost navigation fumbling plugin](https://moodle.org/plugins/local_boostnavigation). Moodle doesn't make it easy to change, but that plugin will give you admin tools to customize the nav drawer.